# How to dynamically define the 'hero' in 'neon-animated-pages'?

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer-1.0

I have two buttons in a page and I'd like the *clicked* one to play as hero in a transition to another page.

Say I have the first page:

```
<dom-module id="first-page">

  <style>
  .hero_from_1 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
  .hero_from_2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-button class="hero_from_1" raised on-tap="tapHandler_1">First Hero</paper-button>
    <paper-button class="hero_from_2" raised on-tap="tapHandler_2">Second Hero</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>

    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'first-page',

        tapHandler_1: function(ev){
          document.getElementsByClassName('hero_from_1')[0].setAttribute('id','hero_from');
          document.getElementsByClassName('hero_from_2')[0].removeAttribute('id');
          this.fire('second-page');
        },

        tapHandler_2: function(ev){
          document.getElementsByClassName('hero_from_1')[0].removeAttribute('id');
          document.getElementsByClassName('hero_from_2')[0].setAttribute('id','hero_from');
          this.fire('second-page');
        },

        behaviors: [Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior],
        properties: {
          animationConfig: {
            value: function(){
              return {
                'entry':{
                  name: 'fade-in-animation',
                  node: this
                },
                'exit':[{
                  name: 'hero-animation',
                  id: 'hero',
                  fromPage: this
                },{
                  name: 'fade-out-animation',
                  node: this
                }]
              }
            }
          },
          sharedElements: {
            value: function() {
              return {
                'hero': this.$.hero_from // changes in ids do not affect hero!!!
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

with a standard `sharedElements` property, as documented in the project pages (https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations#page-transitions).

The problem is that even if I exchange the `id` of the buttons right after a click or tap event, the change does not propagate to the `sharedElements` function, and the animation does not work.

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ferdinandkraft/qzxzeb1u/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `sharedElements`' function is evaluated at creation/attachment time, so it will not keep track of changing `id`s.

I've found a way to work aroud this, simply by setting the `sharedElements` property right after the tap event, just like any other property:

```
<dom-module id="first-page">

  <style>
  .hero_from_1 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
  .hero_from_2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-button class="hero_from_1" raised on-tap="tapHandler">First Hero</paper-button>
    <paper-button class="hero_from_2" raised on-tap="tapHandler">Second Hero</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>

    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'first-page',

        tapHandler: function(ev){
          this.sharedElements = {'hero': ev.target};  /////// here!!!
          this.fire('second-page');
        },

        behaviors: [Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior],
        properties: {
          animationConfig: {
            value: function(){
              return {
                'entry':{
                  name: 'fade-in-animation',
                  node: this
                },
                'exit':[{
                  name: 'hero-animation',
                  id: 'hero',
                  fromPage: this
                },{
                  name: 'fade-out-animation',
                  node: this
                }]
              }
            }
          },
          /* sharedElements removed! */
        }
      })
    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Note that `ev.target` will be the clicked button, so a single `tapHandler` will do the job!

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ferdinandkraft/b1sw1q2o/